# Get DNF from Karnaugh map

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

The following boolean expression in `CNF` form

$$ (x \lor y) \land (x \lor \lnot z) $$

Has been mapped into the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) below

\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline
-       & yz & y\lnot z & \lnot y \lnot z & \lnot y z \\ \hline
x       & 1  & 1        & 1               & 1         \\ \hline
\lnot x & 0  & 1        & 0               & 0         \\ \hline
\end{array}

How can I get the `DNF` from this Karnaugh map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any covering that includes the 1s and nothing else will give you a correct DNF.

So you could do each of the 5 individually:

$$xyz \lor xyz' \lor xy'z' \lor xy'z \lor x'yz'$$

Or you could do the top left 2, top right 2, and bottom 1:

$$xy \lor xy' \lor x'yz'$$

Or you could do the entire top row and the entire second column:

$$x \lor yz'$$

Which is the minimal DNF.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but from the map, how would I derive the original `CNF` expression?

Comment: @sudoman Cover the zeros and negate it.  So the bottom 2 corners are covered by $x'z$ and the bottom right is covered by $x'y'$, so $(x'z \lor x'y')'$ which is $(x \lor z')(x \lor y)$.